# SOAP .net web service: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, web-services, soap

When i try to call my webservice do i get the following error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/GetFlights. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

http://sogaardlameduck.azurewebsites.net/LameDuckService.asmx?WSDL

[image]

When we use the webservice in other .net programs do we not have any problems, but all Java applicaitons fail with this error. What we we missing to support SOAPAction?

This is our web service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://sogaardlameduck.azurewebsites.net/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class LameDuckService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private TravelGoodEntities entities;
        private BankService bankService;
        private int groupNumber;
        private accountType account;

        public LameDuckService()
        {
            entities = new TravelGoodEntities();
            bankService = new BankService();
            groupNumber = 10;
            account = new accountType()
            {
                number = "50208812",
                name = "LameDuck"
            };
        }

        [WebMethod(Description = "Book a flight")]
        public int BookFlight(int bookingId, CreditCardModel model)
        {
            var flight = entities.Flights.Where(x => x.Id == bookingId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (flight == null)
                throw new FlightNotFoundException();

            // count reservations
            var count = flight.Flight_Reservations.Count;
            if(count >= flight.Seats)
                throw new NoAvailableSeatsException();

            try
            {
                if (!bankService.validateCreditCard(groupNumber, new creditCardInfoType()
                {
                    name = model.Name,
                    number = model.Number,
                    expirationDate = new expirationDateType()
                    {
                        year = model.ExpirationDateYear,
                        month = model.ExpirationDateMonth
                    }
                }, flight.Price))
                    throw new CreditCardValidationFailedException();

                if (!bankService.chargeCreditCard(groupNumber, new creditCardInfoType()
                {
                    name = model.Name,
                    number = model.Number,
                    expirationDate = new expirationDateType()
                    {
                        year = model.ExpirationDateYear,
                        month = model.ExpirationDateMonth
                    }
                }, flight.Price, account))
                    throw new CreditCardChargeFailedException();
            }
            catch (SoapException e)
            {
                throw new CreditCardValidationFailedException();
            }

            var reservation = new DataAccess.Flight_Reservations()
            {
                FlightId = flight.Id,
                Booked = DateTime.UtcNow
            };
            entities.Flight_Reservations.Add(reservation);
            entities.SaveChanges();

            return reservation.Id;
        }
        [WebMethod(Description = "Search for flights")]
        public List<Models.Flight> GetFlights(FlightSearchModel model)
        {
            var select = entities.Flights.Select(x => x);

            if (model.DestinationLocation != null)
                select = select.Where(x => x.DestinationLocation == model.DestinationLocation);
            if (model.DepartureLocation != null)
                select = select.Where(x => x.DepartureLocation == model.DepartureLocation);
            if (model.Date != new DateTime())
                select = select.Where(x => x.DepartueTime.Year == model.Date.Year &&
                    x.DepartueTime.Month == model.Date.Month &&
                    x.DepartueTime.Day == model.Date.Day);

            return select.Select(x => new Models.Flight()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Airline = x.Airline,
                ArrivalTime = x.ArrivalTime,
                Carrier = x.Carrier,
                DepartueTime = x.DepartueTime,
                DepartureLocation = x.DepartureLocation,
                DestinationLocation = x.DestinationLocation,
                Price = x.Price,
                Seats = x.Seats
            }).ToList();
        }
        [WebMethod(Description = "Cancel a flight")]
        public bool CancelFlight(int bookingId, CreditCardModel model)
        {
            var booking = entities.Flight_Reservations.Where(x => x.Id == bookingId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (booking == null)
                throw new FlightNotFoundException();

            var flight = entities.Flights.Where(x => x.Id == booking.FlightId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (flight == null)
                throw new FlightNotFoundException();

            if (!bankService.refundCreditCard(groupNumber, new creditCardInfoType()
            {
                name = model.Name,
                number = model.Number,
                expirationDate = new expirationDateType()
                {
                    year = model.ExpirationDateYear,
                    month = model.ExpirationDateMonth
                }
            }, flight.Price, account))
                throw new UnableToRefundException();

            entities.Flight_Reservations.Remove(booking);
            entities.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
        [WebMethod(Description = "Get a flight by booked id")]
        public Models.Flight GetFlightByBookedId(int bookingId)
        {
            var booking = entities.Flight_Reservations.Where(c => c.Id == bookingId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (booking == null)
                throw new FlightNotFoundException();

            var x = entities.Flights.Where(c => c.Id == booking.FlightId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x == null)
                throw new FlightNotFoundException();
            return new Models.Flight()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Airline = x.Airline,
                ArrivalTime = x.ArrivalTime,
                Carrier = x.Carrier,
                DepartueTime = x.DepartueTime,
                DepartureLocation = x.DepartureLocation,
                DestinationLocation = x.DestinationLocation,
                Price = x.Price,
                Seats = x.Seats
            };
        }
        [WebMethod(Description = "Get a flight by id")]
        public Models.Flight GetFlight(int id)
        {
            var x = entities.Flights.Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x == null)
                throw new FlightNotFoundException();
            return new Models.Flight()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Airline = x.Airline,
                ArrivalTime = x.ArrivalTime,
                Carrier = x.Carrier,
                DepartueTime = x.DepartueTime,
                DepartureLocation = x.DepartureLocation,
                DestinationLocation = x.DestinationLocation,
                Price = x.Price,
                Seats = x.Seats
            };
        }
    }
```

Update:
I get the show error on: http://wsdlbrowser.com/soapclient?wsdl_url=http%3A%2F%2Fsogaardlameduck.azurewebsites.net%2FLameDuckService.asmx%3FWSDL&function_name=GetFlights

But if i use: http://www.soapclient.com/ Do i not have any problems:
[image]
[image]